# Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata

Tags: eclipse, spring, osgi, powermock, geronimo

I am getting this error on server startup in eclipse. The unit test using `PrepareForTest` annotation runs fine.

I have added mockito-core, powermock-module-junit4, powermock-api-mockito as dependencies in `pom.xml`.

What could be the causes of this error? Thanks!

```
2014-02-21 09:41:55,896 WARN  [AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor] Failed to classload type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest not found from bundle [com.app.tool]
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:186)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:182)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.access$201(GeronimoStandardContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:723)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.startInternal(GeronimoStandardContext.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebApplication.doRun(WebApplication.java:255)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebApplication.run(WebApplication.java:125)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebContainerExtender$WebApplications.register(WebContainerExtender.java:326)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebContainerExtender.deploy(WebContainerExtender.java:257)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebContainerExtender.access$100(WebContainerExtender.java:63)
    at org.apache.geronimo.osgi.web.extender.WebContainerExtender$WebBundleTrackerCustomizer.addingBundle(WebContainerExtender.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:482)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:234)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1523)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:299)
    at org.apache.geronimo.aries.ApplicationUpdateHelper.updateBundle(ApplicationUpdateHelper.java:167)
    at org.apache.geronimo.aries.ApplicationGBean.updateApplicationContent(ApplicationGBean.java:184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.KernelGBean.invoke(KernelGBean.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ReflectionMethodInvoker.java:34)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanOperation.invoke(GBeanOperation.java:131)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.invoke(GBeanInstance.java:883)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.invoke(BasicKernel.java:245)
    at org.apache.geronimo.system.jmx.MBeanGBeanBridge.invoke(MBeanGBeanBridge.java:172)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:792)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1486)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:96)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1327)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1426)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:847)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor54.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:602)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:327)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.findClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.java:99)
```

Answer (score 1):

So this code cannot find `org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest`. As it seems related to osgi I would expect some misconfiguration on the OSGI manifest of this code.

You should investigate in that direction, ie why the eclipse OSGI classloader refuses to load it. You may need to add more OSGI rules (with BND for example) as you seem to have several dependencies.